# In C++ if I reference an object with a deallocating destructor ~MyClass, will the reference going out of scope invoke the destructor?

Tags: c++, reference, scope

Will the following work, always?

```
class MyCLass {
    int *pInt;
public:
    MyCLass() {
        pInt = new int;
        *pInt = 42;
    }
    ~MyCLass() {
        delete pInt;
        printf("Goodbye cruel world!");
    }
    void func1() {
        printf("Hello World %d", *pInt);
    }
};

MyCLass foo;
{
    MyClass &bar = foo;
    //Do stuff
}
foo.func1();
```

I am worried that in it's mandate to exactly emulate the original object `bar` will cause invocation of the destructor as it goes out of scope.

Comment: `MyCLass foo = new MyClass();` <-- That would not work unless `MyCLass` had a constructor that took a `MyClass` pointer.

Comment: Syntax error, well spotted, thanks cli_hit, the principle remained intact.

Comment: What the constructor does is entirely irrelevant to the question. You might just ask if the end of the lifetime of the reference leads to a call of the destructor of the referee. Which, of course, is false.

Comment: There is neither "mandate" nor "emulation" in C++. A reference is simply an alias.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No it won't.  The storage is entire related to foo in your example.  When foo goes out of scope the destructor will get called.

Of course, if you still had a reference to that object the reference would be referencing a now non-existent object and that could give you issues.

Referencing does not emulate the original object.  All it does is say that while that object is in existence then any call through the reference will be re-directed to that object.

Comment: I appreciate (your quick response and) your advice that it does not emulate the object, from a C background it appeared to me exactly what it was doing and was why I stuck to pointers so long.

Comment: @John:  A reference and a pointer are almost the same thing.  If you check the assembler you'll find that references are often implemented in the same way as pointers.

Comment: References are no reseatable, while pointers are. It doesn't really matter how they are implemented, because you will not be able to use a reference like a pointer without getting undefined behaviour.

Comment: I'm confused by the answer. You say that "When foo goes out of scope the destructor will get called." but I thought the question was what would happen when bar goes out of scope.

Answer (score 1):

References and (raw) pointers to an object don't manage it's lifetime. Therefore when either go out of scope the real object won't be destroyed. You couldn't create references or pointers to stackallocated Objects otherwise, since they would then be destroyed several times (when the reference/pointer goes out of scope and when the object itself goes out of scope). In my opinion the easiest way to understand c++ references is to think of them as pointers which can't be reassigned an are automatically dereferenced with every access (basically syntactical sugar to hide the pointer from the programmer).

As a sidenote, your code is not correct c++. `MyCLass foo = new MyClass()` declares a (stackallocated) object of type `MyClass`, but tries to assign the result of `new MyClass()` to it, which is a pointer to a heap allocated object of Type `MyClass`. The correct way to initialize `foo` would be `MyClass foo;`